# Are tool recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It has been a long time since I was active on Alcohol.SE and I wanted to check to see if asking for a tool/app recommendation questions were on topic before I posted a question and opened myself up to downvotes. Other SE's have varying rules on this from my personal experience and I wanted to check first.

Specifically I wanted to ask for a recommendation for a website/application with recipes based on an entered liquor/ingredient library with a few more qualifications to avoid list answers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a definitive answer, but to this point, we don't have a specific close reason for them, and the questions in this vein haven't caused issues in the past, so I think a well formulated question like this is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

**Are tool recommendations on topic?**

My thoughts on this matter are that tool recommendation questions should be viewed as on topic providing that they genuinely are in volved in the wine, beer and alcohol industries.